# Importing an excel sheet into Python with xlrd

Tags: python, xlrd

I am looking to import an excel sheet into Python using the `xlrd` package.

Here is my example data [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjc1a.jpg)

Here is my example for code 1 （Basically extracting column 1 and 2 separately then combining them into a dataframe):

```
audiences = audience_sheet.col_values(0)
language = audience_sheet.col_values(1)

data_url = pd.DataFrame()

data_url['All_Audiences'] = audiences
data_url['All_Languages'] = language
```

However, I realized that using this approach means that my data will not line up properly in python. For e.g. Audience 68 is supposed to be "FR" but the output ends up with "DE".

How should I go about extracting both lists and making sure that their values line up? I am using XLRD instead of openpyxl because I have an older version of excel.

Comment: Wait. So you're using `xlrd` to read an Excel sheet, just to load it into a dataframe? Are you aware of [`pd.read_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas-read-excel)?

Comment: Since you are already using pandas to create a dataframe, there is no need to use xlrd. Pandas can read an excel file directly as pointed out by @Tomerikoo